# Is it possible to manage multiple non-related Models from a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I manage multiple non-related Models from a Rails form?

Should I have only one controller for all Models or for each Model one controller?

this is my controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def new
         @word=Word.new
         @verb=Verb.new
         @adjektiv=Adjektiv.new
         @adverb=Adverb.new
  end
  def create
    @word=Word.create(params[:word])
    @verb=Verb.create(params[:verb])
    @adjektiv=Adjektiv.create(params[:adjektiv])
    @adverb=Adverb.create(params[:adverb])

    if @word.save || @verb.save || @adjektiv ||  @adverb
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def index
        @word=Word.find(:all)
        @verb=Verb.find(:all)
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(:all)
        @adverb =Adverb.find(:all)
  end
  def edit
        @word=Word.find(params[:id])
        @verb=Verb.find(params[:id])
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(params[:id])
        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @word =Word.find(params[:id])
    if @word.update_attributes(params[:word])  ||   @verb.update_attributes(params[:verb])  || @adjektiv.update_attributes(params[:adjektiv]) || @adverb.update_attributes(params[:adverb])
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Considering how your controller is looking, you should use multiple forms.  It appears you're only working on one at a time?  On edit, you find 4 different models by *the same id*?  On create, you redirect to index if *any* save?  Clearly you want to operate on them independently.  Use controllers and forms for each resource.

Comment: that means i can not do that in one form?

Comment: Based on the images you posted below, it seems you actually want multiple forms, one on each accordion tab.

Comment: hte answer of my Question is :NO

Answer (score 0):

You can manage several models from one form. ( But I think use missed something in application architecture if you want to do it as you explained ). You should not need several controllers - use one. For ex.: just create new instances of models in `new` action, validate and save them in `create` action. Same for `edit`/`update` actions.
I think you also should use `form_tag` instead  of `form_for` beacause there will be no *parent* model to process.

Comment: Thank you ,but hier another problem in edit occured.when i tried to edit record 3 from Table A ,all of record 3 from another tables are show to me .How can i avoid that? you can see my edit function in latest post

Comment: Excuse me? but I don't understand what do you mean 'all of record 3 from another tables are show to me'. They definetly will. Because you editing them. I think you should change the behaviour of your application. Maybe you should create/update models in separate controllers and separate views

Comment: This is exactly my Question.My Scnario is:my project is about German language( that save the German words). I have three Tables (Word for Nammen, Adverb for adverbs,Adjektiv for Adjectivs and Adverb for Adverbs) of course in my scnario(thst is not optimal) there is no realation between Tables.I have one form that user can add adverb OR adjective or....(i use accordion and each one has a tab in accordion) and i want to give a possibility to user to edit one recordin that page....What do you mean? can i implement my scnario?  you can see also : http://babakbsn.persiangig.com/UI11.png   and ...

Comment: that means,there is no solution to have all of tabs in **one form** and only one record send to one tab( records with the same id doesn't send  to each tabs) ?